# Disable button if the user inputs an invalid email address - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have a TextBox so the user can enter their email address. I have implemented the IDataErrorInfo interface and have a message that pops up telling the user that their email address is an invalid format.

If the user inputs an invalid email and presses the submit button, it is still saved to the database. How can I disable the button if the user has inputted an invalid email address, or display an error message?

```
// Check to see if email is valid
    #region
            private bool IsValidEmailAddress()
            {
                try
                {
                    MailAddress address = new MailAddress(EmailAddress);
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    #endregion


        // Displays text error IDataErrorInfo
        private string ValidateEmailAddress()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailAddress))
                return "Email Address Cannot Be Empty";
            else if (!IsValidEmailAddress())
                return "Email Address Must Be A Valid Format";
            else return null;
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Data trigger to stop button being pressed if email is invalid

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValidEmailAddress, ElementName=EmailAddressTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Property code to show invalid address

```
#region
public bool isValidEmailAddress;
public bool IsValidEmailAddress
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            MailAddress address = new MailAddress(EmailAddress);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("IsValidEmailAddress");
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Turn the `IsValidEmailAddress()` method into a property with change notification (e.g. `IsValidEmailAddress`) and bind the Button's IsEnabled property to it.

Comment: I've managed to successfully implement what you suggested thanks, is there a way I can make it work in a resource directory? As the resource directory won't know about the IsValidEmailAddress property @Clemens

Answer (score 0):

You can use text_changed event, which could pass the value of the textbox to a helper class, that validates it. Like this:

```
public static class ValidatorExtensions
{
   public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string s)
   {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$");
    return regex.IsMatch(s);
   }
 }
```

and then when the text changes:

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  bool result = ValidatorExtensions.IsValidEmailAddress( myTextBox.Text );
 }
```

Comment: Why TextChanged? Isn't better, as said, Bind IsValidEmailAddress property?